# Why this is not an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
file = open("fileWithNumbers","r")

numList = [1]

for num in numList :
  for line in file :
    line = line.rstrip()
    numList.append(line)

file.close()
```

I'm currently coding a college assignment and I can't figure out how to make this piece of code an infinite loop. It seems that the outer for-loop ends when one iteration over the textfile is done.

I was expecting that this piece of code runs infinitely because it's iterating over a list that is increasing each iteration.

Actually this is not the exact same scenario that I'm dealing with in my real code, but it resumes perfectly the problem that I'm having. I need that the outer for-loop doesn't end with one iteration of the inner loop. Thank you so much!

Comment: The outer loop executes for each `num` in `numList`. That's obviously a finite list (it's `[1]`). The inner loop is appending to `numbers`.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the code snippet. Now it's right.

Comment: After the first iteration, the file position is at the end and `for line in file` will bail out immediately, without executing the loop body.

Comment: @usr2564301 It worked! I reset the file pointer position with file.seek(0) and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For infinite loops use `while` loop:

```
while True:
    # some python code that I want 
    # to keep on running forever
```

in your case

```
file = open("fileWithNumbers","r")

numList = [1]

while True:
  for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
```

Moreover you are appending to `numbers` and iterating over `numList`

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a list, not the file. So your original file (what you're iterating) never is altered.

Answer (score 0):

You file ends after the first iteration. If you want it to be inifint you need to read the file again or iterate over a list

```
# file = open("fileWithNumbers","r") # see line below ...
file_lines = list(open("fileWithNumbers","r"))

numList = [1]

for num in numList :
   for line in file_lines: # this list will always contain the numbers, not a file that ends ...
       line = line.rstrip()
       numList.append(line)

file.close()
```

I hope the counter example explains it.